# Запятая после противопоставления с союзом "а"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "себя" в данном предложении: "В услугах Филиппа кооператив не нуждается, так как работает не по индивидуальным проектам, а на себя и черпает идеи из заморских изданий"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В услугах Филиппа кооператив не нуждается, так как **работает** **не по индивидуальным проектам, а на себя** **и черпает идеи** из заморских изданий.*

Запятая не нужна, так как одиночный союз И связывает однородные сказуемые. При этом каждое сказуемое имеет свой распространитель: работает (как?) и черпает идеи (откуда?).

В конце сочетания  ***не по индивидуальным проектам, а на себя*** запятая не ставится, так как НЕ...А относится к  однородным обстоятельствам (здесь нет уточнения или пояснения, которые могли бы обособляться).